# Textbox with InputBox type behaviour in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, forms

When the form first loads up, I am able to enter the password in TextBox. If the password is wrong, it goes into second attempt (For Loop) but skips prompting user to enter a password. What can I do to make the code execution stop at this line of code and proceed further only when a password has been enterered?

[image]

```
 For count = 1 To 3
    AttemptMessage.Caption = "Attempt " & count & " of 3"
    If httpRequest.Status = 200 Then
        ' Get the correct password from the online text file
        correctPassword = httpRequest.responseText

        ' Prompt the user to enter their password
        enteredPassword = UserEntry.Value

        ' Check if the entered password matches the correct password
        If enteredPassword = correctPassword Then
            MsgBox "Password is correct. Access granted."
            GoTo Label2
        Else
            If count < 3 Then
            IncorrectPassword.Caption = "Incorrect Password. Please Try Again"
            UserEntry.Value = ""
            GoTo Label1
            ElseIf count = 3 Then
            MsgBox "Password is incorrect. Access denied."
            ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If
        End If
    Else
        ' Handle the request error
        MsgBox "Failed to retrieve the correct password from the online source."
    End If
 Label1:
 Next count
 Label2:
 Unload Me
```

Comment: Do you have code on the `CommandButtonOK_Click` event ? On which event is the code you have shown ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes, you are right. Code shown is an execution command from clicking this OK button.

Answer (score 1):

to solve this you need make the loop inside the else code block of wrong
password to be like this

```
AttemptMessage.Caption = "Attempt " & Count & " of 3"
If httpRequest.Status = 200 Then
    ' Get the correct password from the online text file
    correctPassword = httpRequest.responseText

    ' Prompt the user to enter their password
    enteredPassword = UserEntry.Value

    ' Check if the entered password matches the correct password
    For Count = 1 To 3
    If enteredPassword = correctPassword Then
        MsgBox "Password is correct. Access granted."
        Exit For
        
        
    Else
        
            If Count < 3 Then
            IncorrectPassword.Caption = "Incorrect Password. Please Try Again"
            UserEntry.Value = ""
            ElseIf Count = 3 Then
            MsgBox "Password is incorrect. Access denied."
            ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If
        
    End If
    Next Count
    Unload Me
Else
    ' Handle the request error
    MsgBox "Failed to retrieve the correct password from the online source."
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

When using an InputBox, the InputBox Object is destroyed after you interact with it and hence it is possible to open it again in a loop. In the case of the userform, the form is still open when you click on that button. And I believe your above code in executed when you click the command button in the form. You have 2 options (**Untested**).

**OPTION 1 (No Loop)**

This is how I would do it without a loop.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Attempts As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Attempts > 3 Then
        MsgBox "Password is incorrect. 3 attempts are over.", vbOKOnly, "Access denied."
        Unload Me 'ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If httpRequest.Status = 200 Then
        ' Get the correct password from the online text file
        correctPassword = httpRequest.responseText

        ' Prompt the user to enter their password
        enteredPassword = UserEntry.Value

        ' Check if the entered password matches the correct password
        If enteredPassword = correctPassword Then
            MsgBox "Password is correct. Access granted."
        Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect Password. Please Try Again"
            
            UserEntry.Text = ""
            UserEntry.SetFocus

            Attempts = Attempts + 1               
            AttemptMessage.Caption = "Attempt " & Attempts & " of 3"
        End If
    Else
        ' Handle the request error
        MsgBox "Failed to retrieve the correct password from the online source."
    End If
End Sub
```

Check for the count in the Command Button Click event and then handle it without a loop.

**OPTION 2 (Loop)**

Call the userform in a loop like you do with the Inputbox. I would still recommend Option1.

```
Do While Attempts < 4
    Set frm = New UserForm1
    frm.Show
    
    Attempts = Attempts + 1
Loop
```